# A question in the proof that $\lambda^d (\{x\}) = 0$

Tags: measure-theory

I was asked to prove that the Lebesgue measure of $\{x\}$ is zero $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d$. This is how I did it.

Let $A_k = [x_1, x_1 + \frac{1}{k}) \times [x_2, x_2 + \frac{1}{k}) \dots [x_d, x_d + \frac{1}{k})$ then

$$
\lambda^d (A_k) = \prod_{j = 1}^{d} (x_j + \frac{1}{k} - x_j) = k^{-d}
$$
Now $A_k \downarrow \{x\}$, now I would like to use that $\lambda^d (\{x\}) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \lambda^d (A_k) $ but then I must be certain that $\lambda^d (B) < \infty \ \forall B \in \text{ Borel sets of } \mathbb{R}$. How can I be certain of that?

Comment: Did you mean to write $\lambda^d(A_k)$ instead of $\lambda^d(x)$ in front of the product?

Comment: yes, thanks @Dominik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lebesgue measure (as any measure) is monotonic:
$$\{x\} \subset A_k \implies \lambda(\{x\}) \leq \lambda(A_k) = k^{-d} = \dfrac{1}{k^d}$$
Since $k$ is an arbitrary integer, you can let $k \to \infty$, so that
$$0 \leq \lambda(\{x\}) \leq \lim_{k \to \infty}\; \dfrac{1}{k^d} = 0$$
as desired.

---

I don't see what you mean with "$\lambda^d (B) < \infty \ \forall B \in \text{ Borel sets of } \mathbb{R}$". This is wrong (take $B=\Bbb R^d$).

However, it is true that $\lambda^d(K) < \infty$ for any compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: In my book the have 3 conditions for when a map $\mu$ is a measure. i) $\mu (\emptyset) = 0$ ii) $\mu ( A \cup B ) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$ when $A,B$ are disjoint. iii) for any increasing seq. $(A_j) \subset A$ with $A_j \uparrow A$ we have $\mu (A) = \lim_j \mu (A_j)$ Then the say that IF  $\mu (A) < \infty$ for all $A$ in the sigma algebra, the third condition iii) can be replaced by. For any decreasing seq. $(A_j) \in A$ with $A_j \downarrow A$ we have $\mu (A) = \lim_j \mu (A_j)$

Comment: But since I didnt Believe myself that $\lambda^d (B) < \infty$ I wanted to ask the question here.

Comment: @Olba12 : the only thing to show is that a measure is indeed monotonic. Assume that $E \subset F$. Then we have the disjoint union $F = E \cup (F \setminus E)$, so that (by ii.) $$\mu(F) = \mu(E) + \mu(F \setminus E) \geq \mu(E).$$

Comment: Yes, that I'm aware of. Just didn't Think of that myself. But I understand what you are saying. I will accept your answer. :)